# How do you make a view fill the space available to it?

Tags: android, layout

I know it must be an easy question... I just don't know how to fix it.

So (Just an example),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button     android:id="@+id/fakeButton"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <Button     android:id="@+id/saveSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveSearch"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This wouldn't work - the first button would make the 2nd invisible. Weights would make it all a percentage game which isn't what I want.

Am I being thick?

**EDIT:** I didn't know it, but it seem's the order is important (from answers). Loading a layout is iterative rather than holistic. You can make the first element a fixed height and the rest of the elements will fill what's left. BUT what I need is to make the final element a fixed height.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use layout_weight exactly for that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button     android:id="@+id/fakeButton"
                android:layout_height="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <Button     android:id="@+id/saveSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveSearch"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this, you'll have the bottom button have the basic height, and the fakeButton take up all the remaining space.

layout_height controls how the remaining space should be split between the different views. Default value is 0 (doesn't take any extra space). If you put both buttons to the same height and a weight of 1.0, then each button will take up 50% of the space.

Comment: I don't understand how this is working (Although don't get me wrong - It /is/ working). Could you give a more detailed explanation please?

Comment: Ah - if a child within a LinearLayout has a layout_weight then it's width (horizontal orientation) or height (vertical orientation) is ignored. Instead it will fill it's container upto the extent of other children with a weight of 0 or other children with a weight > 0 who will share a % of the container with by comparing weight values.

Comment: You actually need to think of this system in 2 passes : first, ignore the weight, do the layouts normally. If the LinearLayout has extra space in it, and some children have a weight > 0, then give a percentage of the extra space (horizontal and/or vertical) to the children which have a weight > 0, proportionnaly to the total weight.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to make `fakeButton` to fill the rest space, right? You can use `android:layout_weight` to do this. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<Button     android:id="@+id/fakeButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button     android:id="@+id/saveSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/saveSearch"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, quite easy solution. Just use FrameLayout and margin property:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button     android:id="@+id/fakeButton"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="Fake button"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dip" />

    <Button     android:id="@+id/saveSearch"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:text="Save search"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it help you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="center"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
 >

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="60dip"
 android:text="button"

/>
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_below="@+id/button"
 android:text="button1"

/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be the other way..
first you should have the fixed element and then the match_parent or fill_parent